# Accessing client certificates smartcard with web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I need to fetch the certificate, and would like to fetch the client, and there is no server, I could do this form:

```
public static X509Certificate2 EscolherCertificado(string serial)
{
    var store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

    var Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates;
    X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serial, false);
    if (fcollection.Count == 1)
    {
        return fcollection[0];
    }
    else { cod = "00000"; msgm = "not found"; return null; }

}
```

But when I publish on the server it does not work. Is there any way I can do this?

I can not get the client certificate, it returns error, because on the server there are no registered certificates.

**EDIT**

I have already been told that it is possible, I just do not know how to do it, the ways I tried does not work.

**EDIT**

Following this [link](https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/01/25/using-client-certificates-in-net-part-5-working-with-client-certificates-in-a-web-project/), I did comply, but it does not work, it does not always find. What can I do to correct this problem?

```
public static X509Certificate2 EscolherCertificado(string serial)
        {
        X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try
        {
            userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = userCaStore.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection findResult = certificatesInStore.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serial, true);
            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;
            if (findResult.Count == 1)
            {
                clientCertificate = findResult[0];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to locate the correct client certificate.");
            }
            cod = "0000"; msgm = clientCertificate.ToString(); return clientCertificate;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            userCaStore.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean with fetch the client certificate? You cannot ask for a certificate of the end user on the server. It’s too late that way. The client would have to send the certificate on their behalf. And you certainly cannot go through the client’s certificate store to look for a certificate yourself. You can only tell the front end server (e.g. IIS or Kestrel) to require a certificate and then you will have to rely on the client to send the right certificate.

Comment: I want it to access the system, the certificate is installed on the client machine, but this way it does not find.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot reach the client Certificates Store.
To do that you have to code a propietary plugin for each browser platform and give the right access permissions to the client.
That's a very painful task.
I wish you good luck with it.
In my case we ended up developing an EXE which has full access to the client hardware and features of the platform.

Here's the code:

```
    private void ElegirCert()
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store store = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("MY", System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection collection = (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection)collection;//.Find(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);

        try
        {

            Cert = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Elegir", "Seleccione el certificado que desea utilizar", System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)[0];

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        store.Close();
```

}

Comment: It did not help me, it's exactly the same thing I do, but it does not work. I need to get the certificate on the client, not the server.

Answer (score 0):

I still think that it is not possible to get the list of client certificates using the sole browser capabilities.
There is a way and it involves creating an extension which communicates with an Executable Native file that does the "hard work". That means, getting the full list of certificates and exposing it to the user.
I think that after that, the user chooses one, then the EXE asks for the cert store password (if it has one), then the exe digitally signs the hash and whatever...

Comment: Mariana, have you found the solution?